# Empty DataFrame error encountered plotting with DateTimeIndex in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a time series with Pandas plotting integration and I am receiving the error `TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot`. Using matplotlib directly works, but I think I am misusing the library and want to make sure I'm not going down the wrong path with my use of Pandas.

Here is what is happening:

I have a data file that contains two columns. The first column is a timestamp and the second column is an elapsed time. Both are in nanosecond units. I'm reading in the data using:

```
data = pd.read_table('trace.log', sep=" ", header=None,
    names=("start", "latency"))
print(data.head())
print(data.dtypes)
```

Which contains this data:

```
            start    latency
0  27668827345634  754210039
1  27668827918895  753710503
2  27668827809194  754495193
3  27668827974232  754464123
4  27669581667404   60338395
start      int64
latency    int64
dtype: object
```

I then convert `start` to `datetime64[ns]` and make this the index, and convert the `latency` to a `timedelta64[ns]`.

```
data.start = pd.to_datetime(data.start, unit="ns")
data.latency = pd.to_timedelta(data.latency, unit="ns")
data.set_index('start', inplace=True)

print(data.head())
print(data.dtypes)
print(data.index)
```

So now I have a time series with a DateTimeIndex and my latency expressed as a time delta:

```
                                      latency
start                                        
1970-01-01 07:41:08.827345634 00:00:00.754210
1970-01-01 07:41:08.827495897 00:00:01.395999
1970-01-01 07:41:08.827574509 00:00:01.395592
1970-01-01 07:41:08.827605687 00:00:01.381083
1970-01-01 07:41:08.827634020 00:00:01.381130
latency    timedelta64[ns]
dtype: object
DatetimeIndex(['1970-01-01 07:41:08.827345634',
               '1970-01-01 07:41:08.827495897',
               ...
               '1970-01-01 08:11:07.739615123',
               '1970-01-01 08:11:07.756520620'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='start', length=437915, freq=None)
```

The problem I see is when I attempt to plot this. Based on examples I have seen I should be able to run:

```
data.latency.plot()
```

to produce a plot of latency vs start time, but I get the following error:

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py in _compute_plot_data(self)
   1092         if is_empty:
   1093             raise TypeError('Empty {0!r}: no numeric data to '
-> 1094                             'plot'.format(numeric_data.__class__.__name__))
   1095 
   1096         self.data = numeric_data

TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot
```

Note that if I plot the data using `plt.plot(data.index, data.latency)` then I get what I expect. I think I must be missing a crucial understanding, or I am seeing a bug. Being able to use the Pandas plotting integration would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `set_major_formatter()` in order to customize your time ticks:

```
import io
import datetime
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = """\
            start    latency
0  27668827345634  754210039
1  27668827918895  753710503
2  27668827809194  754495193
3  27668827974232  754464123
4  27669581667404   60338395
"""
data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\s+', index_col=0)

data.start = pd.to_datetime(data.start, unit="ns")
# convert nanoseconds to seconds
data.latency /= 10**9

# define custom Ticker formatter function
def timeTicks(x, pos):
    return str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=x))

formatter = matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(timeTicks)

ax = data.plot(x='start', y='latency')

# format yticks
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what trick you are referring to. Explicitly setting the 'x' data in the plot command works, but I fully expected that plotting the variable without setting 'x' would use the index for the 'x' data.

Comment: @NoahWatkins, the trick is to use `set_major_formatter()`. I've set `x` explicitly in order to save (to get rid of) `data.set_index('start')` as I thought that you are doing it just for plotting - if it the case you can simply specify your `x` axis - it should be faster.